# Overloading operators with structures in c++

Tags: c++, struct, operator-overloading, structure

So I am doing a simple, (or so I thought) exercise to help build my C++ skills.

I have this simple struct to keep track of date information. I need to overload an operator to display the results. This is a simple function that I have used before in classes, and never had any problems with. However, in this exercise I am getting the following error:

Expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type

Here is my code. The problem function is the `ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Date date)` function and is commented in the code.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<ostream>
    #include "error.h"

    using namespace std;

    inline void keep_window_open(string s)
    {
        if (s == "") return;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(120, '\n');
        for (;;) {
            cout << "Please enter " << s << " to exit\n";
            string ss;
            while (cin >> ss && ss != s)
                cout << "Please enter " << s << " to exit\n";
            return;
        }
    }
        struct Date {   
            int year;
            int month;
            int day;
        };
        Date today;
        Date tomorrow;

        // Helper functions
        void initializeDay(Date& date, int year, int month, int day)
        {
            if (month < 1 || month > 12)
            {
                error("Invalid month");
            }
            if (day < 1 || day > 31)
            {
                error("Invalid day");
            }
            date.year = year;
            date.month = month;
            date.day = day;
        }

        void addDay(Date& date, int daysToAdd)
        {
            date.day += daysToAdd;
        }       

        // Does not work    
        ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Date date)
        {
            return os << '(' << date.year()
                << ',' << date.month()
                << ',' << date.day()
                << ')';
        }

    int main()
    {           
        initializeDay(today, 2020, 9, 21);  
        tomorrow = today;
        addDay(tomorrow, 1);

        keep_window_open("~");

        return 0;
    }
```

Like I said I have used the problem function before without problem. The only thing I can think of is it is has something to do with the struct, but that doesn't make sense to me. So I am thinking it maybe something else.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time and your help.

Comment: Don't post just a small part of the error message. Give the whole error message in full and also what line number it refers to. Also you should fix your code formating. The intendation is very confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your structure does not implement any method.
Instead of calling `date.year()` simply call `date.year`

Answer (score 2):

this is the cause:
you are doing `date.year()`
but `year` is a member of the structure and not a function... so you have to do `date.year` instead

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Date date)
{
    return os << '(' << date.year
        ....etc
}
```